# Is there a way to run a debugger on SmartDevice C++ DLL when it runs inside SmartDevice C# application?

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, import, smart-device

I am using SmartDevice C++ DLL for my SmartDevice C# application as follows:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("myCppDll.dll")]
private static extern bool Foo();
```

But it seems that there are a lot of bugs inside the DLL.

Strange thing is that when I test the DLL on Visual C++ project, every method inside the DLL works fine.

It seems that I get problems when I import the DLL into SmartDevice C# application.

I really want to run a debugger on the DLL not the C# application.

But Visual Studio 2008 does not support the option. (I think. I maybe wrong.)

Please someone tell me that I am wrong and I can run a debugger on the DLL in this situation.

Comment: can't you just attach the debugger to the application and put a breakpoint in the c++ source? at least that what I do to debug C++ dlls loaded by a c# application, only it's not for SmartDevice but I doubt that matters

Comment: The debugger doesn't load up C++ dll onto debugger when running C# application, at least for SmartDevice. :(